# Finding a specific ID using Rest in Grails

Tags: rest, grails

I'm exploring the RESTful domain capabilities in Grails 3.1.4 and am getting odd results.  For example, I have this domain object (and no corresponding controller):

```
package resttest

import grails.rest.*

@Resource(readOnly = false, formats = ['json', 'xml'])
class Book {
    String name
}
```

Querying all objects seems to work OK:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/book
[{"id":1,"name":"The Time Machine"},{"id":2,"name":"Moby Dick"}]
```

But getting a specific object fails:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/book/1
{"message":"Not Found","error":404}
```

I must be doing something wrong, but simple I can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid uri needs to be provided in `@Resource` after which the endpoint can be accessed. I would use as below for a `Book` resource (note plural `books` instead of `book`).

```
import grails.rest.Resource

@Resource(uri = "/books", readOnly = false, formats = ['json', 'xml'])
class Book {
    String name
}
```

Result:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/books
[{"id":1,"name":"The Time Machine"},{"id":2,"name":"Moby Dick"}]
$ curl http://localhost:8080/books/1
{"id":1,"name":"The Time Machine"}
```

Comment: Yes, of course!  I was lulled into a false sense of security by the create-domain-resource command, which does not even add a placeholder for uri :-O

Comment: Yes, I can see that. Maybe this can be good feature to add to the template itself defaulting the uri to the domainName plural, to avoid issues like above. You can create an [issue in grails-core](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues) as an improvement, if you like.

Comment: Issue created: [grails-core #9812](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9812)